# When focus goes to a link in first time, screen reader will not read double tap to activate

Tags: javascript, html, focus, wai-aria, screen-readers

I tried this code but screen reader will not read as "double tap to activate".

```html
<div>
  <a id="sidebar_myatt" tabindex="0" data-url="https://m.att.com/myatt/#/login" href="#">
    <span aria-hidden="true">myAT&T</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

```javascript
$('#sidebar').click(function () {
    $('#sidebar_myatt').attr('title', 'my a t & t');
    $('#sidebar_myatt').focus();
    $('#sidebar_myatt').css("outline", "none");
}
```

Comment: which screen reader and browser are you using?

Comment: Google talkback and chrome browser

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: I'm not able to test right now, but I imagine your problem might be because you have an empty (to screen readers) anchor tag that has a hashtag href value, so it doesn't register as a link to TalkBack. You are using an anchor tag but then taking away all of the built in functionality of the anchor tag, so it could cause problems to screen readers. 
Also, the tabindex attribute is unnecessary as the anchor will already be in the tab order.

Comment: It's also difficult to troubleshoot without seeing more code. You are putting a title on the anchor when the `#sidebar` is clicked, so the user will have to click the sidebar before the `#sidebar_myatt` gets the title applied. This would leave the `#sidebar_myatt` anchor as an empty anchor that could be skipped by screen readers

Comment: actually first time i tried with the title attr as you said but that time also it was not working so that i tried this in different way. now i found a solution if am updating the attributes in setTimeout function screen reader reads correctly.